# Remove slug name from url locomotivecms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locomotivecms

How can I remove slug name from URL?  I have URL with parent page:

```
host_url/home/index
```

but I need this to be as

```
host_url/index  #without parent slug name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the `routes` as:

```
match '/index', :to => 'home#index', via: [:get]
```

Comment: Atul thanks for your reply but  /index is not fix i.e. any other page will also be there..means it is dynamic "host_url/home/page_name".

Comment: As far as I understand your problem, instead of `index`, you can have different (dynamic) name. But it will redirect to the same controller#method. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If using `resources` in `routes` .

```
resources :users, path: '/'

get '/index' => 'home#index'
```